# Why "a = a + a" is not a cyclic structure where as "a.append(a)" is a cyclic structure?

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
a = [1,2,3]
a = a + [a]
Print(a)
>>> [1,2,3,1,2,3]

a = [1,2,3]
a.append[a]
Print (a)
>>>[1,2,3,[...]]
```

Comment: Thanks for the clarification guys!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

because `+` creates a new object and `append` just appends to the original object. if you append a list to itself there is a cycle.

```
>>> a = [12]
>>> id(a)
4337923136
>>> a = a + [a]
>>> id(a)
4338091360
>>> a
[12, [12]]
>>> a.append(a)
>>> id(a)
4338091360
>>> a
[12, [12], [...]]
>>>
```

Answer (score 1):

Because `[a]` creates another list and add it to a, but `a.append(a)` appends the same list to itself and it will be cyclic, look at the example:

```
In [19]: id(a)
Out[19]: 139994593696008

In [20]: id([a])
Out[20]: 139994605200520
```